# Are crossed factorial design and full factorial design the same concept?

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, fractional-factorial

About crossed factorial design, two factors A and B are crossed, if every level of A can occur in every level of B.

A full factorial/crossed experiment is an experiment
whose experimental units take on all possible combinations of these levels across all such factors.

If I am correct about the above, are crossed factorial design and full factorial design the same concept?

Comment: How do [Graeco-Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Graeco-Latin_square) meet your definitions?

Comment: "Crossed" means that the factors are formally independent, not nested. "Full factorial" = "all main effects + all interaction effects" between factors (plus covariate main effects, if any)

Comment: You might also have a "fractional factorial design", for instance a $2^{3-1}$ design, meaning three variables but only four runs so inteactions cannot be estimated. Such a design is also "crossed" but it is not "full factorial".

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen; Thanks! why isn't " crossed design = full factorial design", given that "two factors A and B are crossed, if every level of A can occur in every level of B"?

Answer (score 3):

(*Crossed*) *factorial design* is **not** always equal to *Full factorial design*.

In this context, the word "crossed" is a synonym of "factorial" (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment)). Both indicates the presence of interactions between factors.

A factorial design can be either:

- [Full](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment) (all possible interactions) or,
- [Fractional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design) (without all interactions, but some).

Therefore, a "factorial design" does not necessarily implies it is "fully crossed".

In the OP's case, where:

> two factors A and B are crossed, if every level of A can occur in every level of B

It will be a full factorial design.

Comment: Thanks! "two factors A and B are crossed, if every level of A can occur in every level of B." So isn't a crossed design full factorial?

Comment: Yes, it is but you did not write the word "full" on question. And there is no need to use "crossed" and "factorial" together, because they are synonyms.

Comment: I meant why isn't " crossed design = full factorial design", given that "two factors A and B are crossed, if every level of A can occur in every level of B"?

Comment: Then, What is the difference between a crossed factorial design and a full factorial design? Why are not igual designs?  I don't understand.  From a crossed factorial design is it possible to get the analysis of all interactions of the factors A, B, AB, AA, BB?  Thanks.

Comment: @cabita, the terminology `crossed factorial design` is redundant, because `crossed` and `factorial` means the same thing, i.e., an experiment has factors w/ usually 2 levels/factor. E.g., factor A = I (levels: with irrigation, without irrigation), factor B = F (with fertilization, without fert.). A `full factorial design` has all possible combinations between factors and levels (in this case $2^2$ --> I+F, no_I+no_F, I+no_F, no_I+F). Yet, a `factorial design` can be [fractional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design), where there are interactions, but not all possible ones.

Comment: Thanks.  I understood, crossed and factorial is the same thing.  Do you now if a completely random design with arrangement factorial of treatments can be analized as a full factorial design? A completely random design with arrangement factorial of treatments is a crossed design and can be analyzed the interactions A, B, AB, AA, BB?.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cabita you are welcome. I am not sure, but I guess if you have all the interactions you can, as long as there are repetitions (more than one plot per treatment). Is this related to your question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105890/difference-between-a-random-design-with-factorial-arrangement-and-a-factorial-mu)? If it is, maybe you can clarify it a little bit (I wrote some tips for you there, see if they help).